# Viewing product details

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am building an e-commerce project, and at the point where I want the user to be able to view the details of a product once they click on a "view" button. I have already rendered the products from a MySQL database to the front end and each of these products has a unique id. How do I go about this? I will include the code below:

This is my index.ejs file

```
    <div class="row">

        <% result.forEach(function(product){ %>

        <div class="product_card col-lg-3">
            <img src="images\<%= product.main_img %>">
            <div class="product_content">
                <p><%= product.product_name %></p>
                <h5>£<%= product.price %></h5>
                <a href="<%= product.id %>" role="button">View</a>
            </div>
        </div>
       
        <% }) %>
        
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Below is my app.js file pointing to the single product page where I want tyhe details of each product to be displayed once view button is clicked from the index.ejs page:

```
app.get('/singleproduct', function(req, res){

res.render('singleproduct')  
})
```

And below is the singleproduct.ejs page where I want the products details to be displayed:

```
<% result.forEach(function(product){ %>
<div class="single_product_main">
<div class="single_product_imgs">
    
  
   <img src="images\<%= product.image %>" alt=""> 
    <div class="small_imgs">
        <img src="images\<%= product.small_img1 %>" alt="">  
        <img src="images\<%= product.small_img2 %>" alt="">  
        <img src="images\<%= product.small_img3 %>" alt=""> 
    </div>
</div>

 <div class="single_product_content"> 
 <h2><%= product.product_name %></h2> 
 <h5>£<%= product.price %></h5> 
 <p><%= product.product_description %></p> 
</div>



  <% }) %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `index.ejs` file you need your link to send the user to `singleproduct/product.id` so something like:

```
<a href="singleproduct/<%= product.id %>" role="button">View</a>
```

Then in your app.js:

```
app.get('/singleproduct/:id', function(req, res){
    // You can access the :id value like so
    const productId = req.params.id;
    // Use the productId to fetch the product details from MySQL
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `id` = ?', 
       [productId], function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        // Log the results to see it returns an array
        console.log(results);
        // Since you selected by id only use the 0 index result
        const product = results[0];
        // Pass the product as the 2nd argument in the res.render method
        res.render('singleproduct',{
           product: product
        }); 
    }); 
});
```

If you are just sending 1 product back to the single view then you don't need a `forEach()` function in your singleproduct.ejs. Something like this will do.

```
<div class="single_product_main">
   <div class="single_product_imgs">
      <img src="images\<%= product.image %>" alt=""> 
      <div class="small_imgs">
         <img src="images\<%= product.small_img1 %>" alt="">  
         <img src="images\<%= product.small_img2 %>" alt="">  
         <img src="images\<%= product.small_img3 %>" alt=""> 
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="single_product_content"> 
      <h2><%= product.product_name %></h2> 
      <h5>£<%= product.price %></h5> 
      <p><%= product.product_description %></p> 
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello @jQueeny. I tried your approach and I keep getting action is not a function. I think I am getting the fetch function wrong. I am new to this so it's been quite a struggle. below is how I wrote my fetch function and the app.get in general.

Comment: ```app.get('/singleproduct/:id', function(req, res){
    
      let productId = req.params.id;
      action = 'SELECT * FROM products where id = ?', function(err, result){
if(err){
    console.log('cannot fetch')
}else{
    console.log('fetch successful')
}
      };

      const product = connection.action(productId)

      res.render('singleproduct', {
        product: product
      })
      
      })```

Comment: I have updaded the answer to provide a basic function to get you started with using the [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) node package. I have used callbacks instead of async/await to keep it a bit more straightforward to follow the docs.

Comment: Thank you so much. I followed the update and it worked. Getting a hold of it! @jQueeny

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer helped please mark it as accepted. Good luck with your project.